# The number of hours can be more than 12 in ASP.NET textbox

Tags: asp.net

I would like it to be possible to have more that 12 hours in my time input type since a user could work more than 12hours on a problem how can I allow this.

```
         <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
  <label for="validationCostComponente">Tiempo cotizado</label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"   TextMode="time"  runat="server" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" ></asp:TextBox>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please choose a username.
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the TextMode property to Number instead of Time. As I understand you correctly, you want to enable the user to enter a duration instead of a time.

Comment: Yes you are correct I want the user to enter the time there task has taken. However I would like there to be hh:mm so it is easyer for the user to insert there time for exemple 43:23    would be 43hours and 23 minutes.

Comment: 43:23 is not a time in any sense, on any clock. You need to use text or numbers and convert it, if necessary. You could use 2 text boxes, one for hours, one for minutes for users to enter ***their*** "times".